# if statement in jQuery each. loop of array

Tags: jquery, arrays, match

I have this array

```
var bmpArrayNames=["strip_cropping", "crop_rotation", "cover_crops", "filter_strips", "grassed_waterway", "conservation_tillage", "binary_wetlands"];
```

and this array

```
var bmpArray=["1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
```

I need to loop through this bmpArray looking to see if the value =1. If it does, I want to replace the value with the value at the same index of the bmpArrayNames. Then I would remove all "0" ultimately ending with bmpArray=["strip_cropping,"crop_rotation"]

I started with this but am not stuck

```
$.each(bmpArray, function(index, value) { 
if (value=="1")
//so if i find a match how do I replace with the same indexed value in the other array.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$.each(bmpArray, function(index, value) {
    if (value == "1") {
        bmpArray[index] = bmpArrayNames[index];
    }
});

$.grep(bmpArray, function(item, index) {
    return bmpArray[index] != "0";
});
```

Input:

```
var bmpArrayNames = ["strip_cropping", 
                     "crop_rotation", 
                     "cover_crops",
                     "filter_strips", 
                     "grassed_waterway", 
                     "conservation_tillage", 
                     "binary_wetlands"];

var bmpArray = ["1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
```

Output:

```
bmpArray : ["strip_cropping", "crop_rotation"];
```

Comment: thanks for the easy solution! I was making more out of it then I needed to!

Answer (score 2):

This will update the bmpArray:

```
$.each(bmpArray, function(index, value) { 
    if (value==="1"){
        bmpArray[index] = bmpArrayNames[index];
    }
});
```

Note that use of the triple equals operator is encouraged, to prevent unintended type coersion.

To remove the zeroes you can use the `grep`function, like so:

```
bmpArray = $.grep(bmpArray, function(item){
    return item !== "0";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if its that you want:

```
["strip_cropping", "crop_rotation"]
```

as a final result you could use jQuery .grep method:

```
var bmpArrayNames = ["strip_cropping", "crop_rotation", "cover_crops", "filter_strips", "grassed_waterway", "conservation_tillage", "binary_wetlands"];
var bmpArray = ["1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];

bmpArrayNames = jQuery.grep( bmpArrayNames, function(item, index) {
    return bmpArray[index] == "1";
});
```

`bmpArrayNames` will now be `["strip_cropping", "crop_rotation"]`